# JPA StackOverflow -- Many to Many and one to one mapping

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping, entitymanager

I am trying to save a JPA entity which has ManytoMany Relationship (Consumer and Product table) and OnetoOne relation with ConsumerDetailstable.Below are my entities

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class)    
    @Entity
    public class Consumer {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private Long  id;
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        
        @JsonManagedReference
        @OnToMany(mappedBy = "consumer")
        private Set<ConsumerProduct> consumerProducts;
        
        @OneToOne
        private CustomerDetails consumerDetails;
    }  

@Entity
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long productId;
    private String productCode;
    
      
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product")
    private Set<ConsumerProduct> consumerProducts; 
}



@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class)   
    @Entity(the join table)
    public class ConsumerProduct {
        @EmbeddedId
        ConsumerProductKey id;
        
       @JsonBackReference
        @ManyToOne
        @MapsId("id")
        @JoinColumn(name = "id")
        private Consumer consumer;
    
        @ManyToOne
        @MapsId("productId")
        @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
        private Product product;
    }
@Embeddable (forgein keys combined as embeded id)
public class ConsumerProductKey implements Serializable {
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long  id;
                
    @Column(name = "product_id")
    private Long productId;
}

@Enitity (one to one relation table)
public class CustomerDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long consumerDtlId;
    
    @OneToOne
    private Consumer consumer;
    
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String country;
}
```

To save the entity am have just extended JPARepository and called save method

```
public class ConsumerRepository<Consumer> Implements JPARepository<Consumer, Long> {
   @Override
    public Consumer S save(Consumer entity) {
        return save(entity);
    };
}
```

I get java.lang.StackOverFlowError at save method.
Anything wrong with my Mappings ?

Question: Since this will be save operation and since Consumer Id is yet to be generated how do I assign to below Entities

ConsumerProduct.ConsumerProductKey (how do i assign Id of consumer table once it is inserted to join table ? will JPA take care of it)

CustomerDetails (how do i assign Id of consumer table once it is inserted to join table ? will JPA take care of it)

EDIT: I have updated the entity  with JsonManagedReference and JsonBackedReference but still i have am facing stackoverflow error

Answer (score 0):

It is due to Consumer trying to access `ConsumerProduct` and ConsumerProduct trying to access `consumer` entity and end up with StackOverflow error.
You should use `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` annotation in `consumer` and `ConsumerProduct` respectivly.

Comment: I tried it but still issue persist , i have updated my question with the JsonManagedReference and JsonBackReference